# How to clear v-model used with a select when options change

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a cascading select (two part select) where the options in the second dropdown are determined by the value of the first dropdown. I do this by having a computed property which is based off of the first select. This then feeds the options into the second select. This mostly works fine.

The problem I'm having is if I have selected an option in the second select (which through v-model sets the value of the bound variable in Vue), and then I change the value of the first select. The options for the second select then update, and in that second select I appear to be selected to the empty option. However, the bound variable still has the previously selected value. I'm assuming this is because updating the option values for the second select doesn't actually trigger an input or change event so v-model doesn't respond to anything. I suppose I could fix this with a watcher, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Coded example is here: https://codepen.io/Slotheroo/pen/ajwNKO/

**JS/Vue:**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selectedFruit: null,
    selectedVariety: null,
    fruits: {
      "apples": [
        {
          name: "honeycrisp",
          madeBy: "applebees",
        },
        {
          name: "macintosh",
          madeBy: "the steves",
        },
        {
          name: "gala",
          madeBy: "ac/dc",
        },
        {
          name: "pink lady",
          madeBy: "Alecia Beth Moore",
        },
      ],
      "pears": [
        {
          name: "d'anjou",
          madeBy: "Maya D'Anjoulou",
        },
        {
          name: "bartlett",
          madeBy: "Anton Yelchin",
        }
      ],
    },
  },
  computed: {
    fruitVarieties: function() {
      return this.fruits[this.selectedFruit]
    }
  },
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <select v-model="selectedFruit">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option v-for="fruitName in Object.keys(fruits)" :value ="fruitName">{{fruitName}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <select v-model="selectedVariety">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option v-for="fruitVariety in fruitVarieties" :value="fruitVariety">{{ fruitVariety.name }}</option>
    </select>
  <div>
  </div>
  <p>Selected variety: {{ selectedVariety }}</p>
</div>
```

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Select 'apples' in the first select
2. Select 'honeycrisp' in the second select
3. Select 'pears' or 'blank' in the first select

**Hoped for result**

selectedVariety returns to null

**Actual result**

selectedVariety still equals honeycrisp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd add an *on-change* handler to the first `<select>` to empty the `selectedVariety` when the selection changes...

```
<select v-model="selectedFruit" @change="selectedVariety = null">
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JByEwy

---

Another option would be to add a *watch* on `selectedFruit` but Vue generally recommends using event handlers.

Comment: I'm getting an infinite load loop when I visit that codepen. Not sure why.

Comment: @Slotheroo not sure what that means. Works fine for me. Try opening it in an incognito window perhaps? In any case, I just opened yours, made the one-line change and clicked "Fork"

Comment: Incognito window worked. Choosing this as the answer since it seems the most straightforward solution, though there's nothing wrong with @Duannx 's answer.

Comment: @Slotheroo I'm not a fan of mutating data properties within computed _getters_. Just doesn't feel right. I've always though of computed properties (those without a _setter_ anyway) as read-only

Comment: I feel exactly the same way, but I think it's a stylistic choice. I think functionally the answers are very similar in that you're just responding to an event, so I think there's nothing conceptually wrong with hijacking the computed property. It just feels dirty to me.

Answer (score 3):

if you're using `version 3.0.0`, there is some feature with `:reset-on-options-change='true'`

e.g

```
<v-select required  :options="filterKaryawan.unit.options" :reset-on-options-change='true' v-model="filterKaryawan.unit.selected" placeholder="placeholder" >
   <template #search="{attributes, events}">
       <input
           class="vs__search"
            v-bind="attributes"
            v-on="events"
            :required="filterKaryawan.unit.selected"
       />
   </template>
</v-select>
```

Comment: It works for me, I used v-select version ^2.6.4.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

The `computed` propertive is actually a `watcher`. So just put the reset value code in it.

```
computed: {
    fruitVarieties: function() {
      this.selectedVariety = null; 
      return this.fruits[this.selectedFruit]
    }
}
```